# Is this Prolog terminology correct? (fact, rule, procedure, predicate, ...)

Tags: prolog, terminology, iso-prolog

Getting the terminology correct is part of the success to communicating a concept and when the wrong terminology is used here at SO with the Prolog tag the respondents nicely point out the mistake.

In reading "Clause and Effect - Prolog Programming for the Working Programmer" by William F. Clocksin in 1997 ([WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/37370671)) is the paragraph

> A Prolog **program** consists of a collection of **procedures**. Each
>   procedure defines a particular **predicate**, being a certain relationship
>   between its **arguments**. A procedure consists of one or more **assertions**,
>   or **clauses**. It is convenient to think of two kinds of clauses: **facts**
>   and **rules**.

While I understand all of the words, is each bold word the currently correct terminology for use when communicating about Prolog?

In particular the use of **rule** seems to be frowned upon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Prolog ISO Standard

> [ISO/IEC 13211-1](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info) (First edition 1995-06-01)
>
> **Information technology - Programming languages - Prolog**
>
> **Part 1**: General Core

which has an extensive glossary on pages 2-10.

> 3.6 **anonymous variable**: A *variable* (represented in a term or *Prolog text* by _) which differs from every other variable (and anonymous
> variable) (see 6.1.2, 6.4.3)
>
> 3.7 **argument**: A *term* which is associated with a *predication* or *compound term*.
>
> 3.9 **arity**: The number of *arguments* of a *compound term*. Syntactically, a non-negative integer associated with a *functor* or
> *predicate*.
>
> 3.10 **assert**, to: To assert a *clause* is to add it to the *user-defined procedure* in the *database* defined by the *predicate* of
> that *clause*.
>
> 3.19 **body**: A goal, distinguished by its context as part of a *rule* (see 3.154).
>
> 3.21 **built-in predicate**: A *procedure* whose *execution* is implemented by the *processor* (see 8).
>
> 3.32 **clause**: A *fact* or a *rule*. It has two parts: a *head*, and a *body*.
>
> 3.35 **complete database** The set of *procedures* with respect to which *execution* is performed (see 7.5).
>
> 3.37 **compound term**: A *functor* of arity `N`, `N` positive, together with a sequence of `N` *arguments*.
>
> 3.45 **control construct**: A *procedure* whose definition is part of the Prolog *processor* (see 7.8).
>
> 3.52 **database**: The set of *user-defined procedures* which currently exist during *execution* (see 7.5).
>
> 3.57 **directive**: A *term* `D` which affects the meaning of *Prolog text* (see 7.4.2) and is denoted in that *Prolog text* by the *directive-term* `:-(D)`.
>
> 3.59 **dynamic** (of a *procedure*): A dynamic *procedure* is one whose *clauses* can be inspected or altered during *execution*, for example by
> *asserting* or *retracting* *clauses* (see 7.5.2).
>
> 3.72 **fact**: A *clause* whose *body* is the *goal* `true`.   NOTE - A fact can be represented in *Prolog text* by a *term* whose *principal functor* is neither `(:-)/1` nor `(:-)/2`.
>
> 3.77 **functor**: An *identifier* together with an *arity*.
>
> 3.81 **goal**: A *predication* which is to be *executed* (see *body*, *query*, and 7.7.3).
>
> 3.84 **head** (of a *rule*): A *predication*, distinguished by its context.
>
> 3.88 **identifier**: A basic unstructured object used to denote an *atom*, *functor name* or *predicate name*.
>
> 3.96 **instantiated**: A *variable* is instantiated with respect to *substitution* if application of the *substitution* yields an *atomic term* or a *compound term*.
>
> 3.113 **named variable**: A *variable* which is not an *anonymous variable* (see 6.1.2, 6.4.3)
>
> A *term* is instantiated if any of its *variables* are instantiated.
>
> 3.129 **predicate**: An *identifier* together with an *arity*.
>
> 3.131 **predicate indicator**: A *compound term* `A/N`, where `A` is an *atom* and `N` is a non-negative integer, denoting one particular *procedure* (see 7.1.6.6).
>
> 3.133 **predication**: A *predicate* with *arity* `N` and a sequence of `N` *arguments*.
>
> 3.136 **procedure**: A *control construct*, a *built-in predicate*, or a *user-defined procedure*. A procedure is either *static* or *dynamic*. A
> procedure is either *private* or *public* (see 7.5).
>
> 3.141 **Prolog text**: A sequence of *read-terms* denoting *directives* and *clauses* (see 6.2, 7.4).
>
> 3.143 **query**: A *goal* given as interactive input to the *top level*.
>
> 3.154 **rule**: A *clause* whose *body* is not the *goal* `true`. During *execution*, if the *body* is true for some *substitution*, then the *head* is also true for that *substitution*. A rule is represented in *Prolog text*
> by a *term* whose *principal functor* is `(:-)/2` where the first *argument* is converted to the *head*, and the second argument is *converted* to the body.
>
> 3.164 **static** (of a *procedure*): A static *procedure* is one whose *clauses* cannot be altered (see 7.5.2).
>
> 3.185 **top level**: A process whereby a Prolog *processor* repeatedly inputs and *executes* * *queries*.
>
> 3.193 **uninstantiated**: A *variable* is *uninstantiated* when it is not *instantiated*.
>
> 3.195 **user-defined procedure**: A *procedure* which is defined by a sequence of *clauses* where the *head* of each *clause* has the same
> *predicate indicator*, and each *clause* is expressed by *Prolog text* or
> has been *asserted* during execution (see 8.9).
>
> 3.200 **variable**: An object which may be *instantiated* to a *term* during *execution*.

## Notes

**Basic overview**

```
h(A,B,C) :- g(A,B),h(B,C),j(A,C).
<------------------------------->  - A (HORN) CLAUSE, which is also a RULE. 
            <------------------>   - BODY of the RULE, which also a GOAL.
                                     ... only one literal: ATOMIC GOAL.
<------>                           - HEAD of the RULE, which can appear
                                     as GOAL depending on context.

f(A,B,C).                          - A CLAUSE with the elided body `true`.
                                     This is a FACT, but _not_ a RULE.
                                     Also called a UNIT CLAUSE.
f(A,B,C)  :- true.                 - Same as above, still not a RULE.
f(A,B,C)  :- !.                    - Is it a RULE? We don't know!

          :- f(A,B,C).             - A DIRECTIVE.
          :- (foo(bar)).           - Another DIRECTIVE.
```

Slightly different definitions can be found at the entry for [Horn Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) a Wikipedia. In particular, "fact" is said to be "a unit clause without variables" - this is not in accordance wit the ISO definition.

**The non-terminal indicator**

In addition to the *predicate indicator* notation `A/N` (`functor/arity`), there is the notation `A//N`, which is not in the ISO standard (or not yet, see [this draft](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#dcg)). It tells the reader that this predicate is used in a [Definite Clause Grammar (DCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) and takes 2 hidden arguments for the input "difference list" (or "list difference") pair in addition to the number of arguments indicated.

In the standard proposal indicated above, it is described as:

> 3.19 **non-terminal indicator**: A compound term `A//N` where `A` is
> an atom and `N` is a non-negative integer, denoting one particular
> non-terminal

Most implementations translate a non-terminal `nt//n` to a predicate `nt/n+2`. However, one cannot rely on the precise way of translation and the outcome of calling a non-terminal directly by calling the corresponding predicate, that is, with the same name and two extra arguments is not defined. In particular the second additional argument has to be handled with care. A direct use might violate steadfastness, in particular when using [dcg-semicontext](/questions/tagged/dcg-semicontext).

**Note on *directive***

The directive can be another way of writing a query. [From the SICStus Prolog manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Queries-and-Directives.html#Queries-and-Directives):

> Queries and directives are ways of directing the system to execute
> some goal or goals. (...) The principal use for directives (as opposed
> to queries) is to allow files to contain directives that call various
> predicates, but for which you do not want to have the answers printed
> out. In such cases you only want to call the predicates for their
> effect, i.e. you do not want terminal interaction in the middle of
> consulting the file.

A directive can also be source file markup, whose position is important (i.e. code meta-information). [From the SWI Prolog manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=module/2) on the `module` directive:

> This directive can only be used as the first term of a source file. It
> declares the file to be a module file, defining a module named *Module*.

The predicates used in a directive may be quite peculiar, giving instructions and predicate meta-information to the Prolog processor. [From the SWI Prolog manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=declare) on "declaring predicate properties":

> This section describes directives which manipulate attributes of
> predicate definitions.

For example, "load the library for constraint logic programming over finite domains":

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

The rule with the empty head `:- foo`, which could be interpreted as `false :- foo` is *not* used in Prolog to express the constraint "it is never the case that *foo*". It *is* used that way in implementations of [Answer Set Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming) like "ASP Prolog" (which has Prolog-y syntax but otherwise is nothing like Prolog).

**Note on *built-in predicate***

In chapter 8, on page 63, we find:

> "A built-in predicate is a procedure which is provided by a
> standard-conforming processor"

Colloquially, "the built-in predicate is part of the Prolog language". Other predicates may be *library predicates* which need to be pulled into the Prolog program by appropriate *directive*. Example from SWI Prolog: [library predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=library).

**Note on *fact***

Colloquially, a "flat fact" is a fact represented by ground term - a term without variables.

**Note on *functor***

This has nothing to do with the "[functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor)" of Category Theory. On the functor of Category Theory, Wikipedia has this to say:

> The word functor was borrowed by mathematicians from the
> philosopher Rudolf Carnap, who used the term in a linguistic
> context; see [function word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word).

And on "function word":

> In linguistics, function words (also called functors) are words
> that have little lexical meaning or have ambiguous meaning and
> express grammatical relationships among other words within a
> sentence, or specify the attitude or mood of the speaker.

So the choice of "functor" for Prolog is a bit unfortunate.

Additionally, the logician [W.V.O Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willard_Van_Orman_Quine) uses the word *functor* in "[Predicate Functors Revisited](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273763)" (and earlier) to describe a *combinator* that rearranges the arguments of the (atomic) predicate that (syntactically) follows it. See also: "[Combinatory Logic - Alternative approaches: basic logic and predicate functors](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combinatory/#AlteApprBasiLogiPredFunc)" at the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

See also the question [Definition of "functor"; Haskell vs. C++](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/421566/definition-of-functor-haskell-vs-c).

**Note on *goal***

The goal can be what one would describe as "simple", e.g. `p(X)`, in which case it is an *atomic goal*, or a tree composed of subgoals e.g. `p(X),q(Y)` because `,` is a predication with the principal functor `(',')/2`.

In fact, goal is generally taken to be anything that can appear as a rule body. For example, `p(X) -> q(Y) ; r(Z)`, with principal functor `;` (not `->`) is absolutely a goal.

The goal could also be a variable resolving to a goal, which might be passed to a meta-predicate like [`call/1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) for example: `X=(Z is 1+2), call(X).`.

A variation is the incomplete atomic goal used by a meta-predicate. This names a callable predicate with some arguments "on the left" pre-set. The meta-predicate will adjoin arguments "on the right". This is called a **closure** although, unlike in functional programming, it isn't actually a function referring to context valid at function creation time.

For example, the three calls all output `u v w`:

```
foo(X,Y,Z) :- format("~q ~q ~q\n", [X,Y,Z]).

maplist(foo,    [u],[v],[w]). % call "foo" with 3 arguments
maplist(foo(u),     [v],[w]). % call closure foo(u) with 2 arguments
maplist(foo(u,v)       ,[w]). % call closure foo(u,v) with 1 argument
```

**Note on *predicate* vs. *procedure* vs. *predicate indicator***

This concept of *predicate* seems to float in the "space of semantics" rather than the "space of syntax":

- the name or declaration of the "predicate thing" is the *predicate indicator*;
- the definition of the predicate of the "predicate thing" is the *procedure* (based presumably on code, Prolog or otherwise).

*Example*:

For the *predicate* `fact` of arity 2 which computes the factorial function:

`fact/2` is the *predicate indicator*, and

```
fact(0,1) :- !.
fact(X,F) :- Xp is (X-1), fact(Xp,Fp), F is (Fp*X).
```

is the possible corresponding *procedure*.

In practice, *predicate* is used to denote any *procedure* as well and one writes the *predicate indicator* to identify it.

A *procedure* which admits to a logical interpretation and allows variables for any of its arguments would a **relation** in the [database interpetation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)) or the [logic interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus_De_Morgan#Relations) of that word.

In "Programming in Prolog (5th ed.)" (Clocksin & Mellish 2003), it is simply said on p. 188 that

> The collection of clauses for a given predicate is called a *procedure*.

**Note on *Prolog text***

A "Prolog program" (a term which is not defined in the ISO Standard) would be the colloquial description of a set of **Prolog texts** to be run by the (possibly standard) processor.

**Prolog text** also includes text entered at the top level which is not a Prolog program, e.g.

```
?- X is 5 * 3.
X = 15.
```

Comment: Of interest: [Summary of Prolog Terminology](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~gwiener/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/prolog-as-meta-lang-pres.pdf) See the end of the slides for `Summary of Prolog Terminology` which has nice graphics.

Comment: Digging out the glossary of SWI Prolog: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary

Comment: Digging out the glossary of SICStus Prolog: https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Glossary.html#Glossary

Comment: @anton-danilov in revision [6](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49931767/revisions) you added *flat fact*. Where did the terminology come from?

Comment: i found no such phrase here. Maybe from Datalog. Anyways **flat** == function free

Comment: Checked _"What You Always Wanted to Know About Datalog (And Never Dared to Ask)"_, Ceri, Gottlob, Tanca, IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering Vol 1, No 1, March 1989. They don't use "flat", just "ground".

Comment: There are "Flat Guarded Horn Clauses", which is something different though: For the Guard part, _the flat restriction only allows primitive (and consequently nonrecursive) predicates in the guard that test the input parameters and perform no output. In the flat regime the computation degenerates to an and-tree and hence the name flat._  [Agent-Oriented Programming: From Prolog to Guarded Definite Clauses](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540666837), Matthew Huntbach & Graem Ringwood, 1999.

Comment: @GuyCoder No, why?

Comment: @GuyCoder I see. :-D But the answer is very specialized. Structurally `(A-B-C)` is a _pair_, although it looks like a _triple_. I once called it a "caterpillar" to oppose to with a list. It has has the last position of the backbone named with C, whereas `[A,B,C]` has the last position unnamed (and uninstantiated). OTOH, (A,B,C) is for me a "conjunction". Contrary to lists, these structures are hard to handle as one always needs a special code case on last position.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer You are correct that it would not fit with the answer to the question. I once had a different but related question and was getting the kind of comments unique to StackOverflow so I removed the other question. Life is much better at the SWI-Prolog forum than here.

Comment: @GuyCoder It is a fact that SO can be quite ego-driven indeed. Such is life in the Zone.

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog Dictionary](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#query). Thanks to [Wisermans](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/swi-prolog-libraries-online-index-of-words/4037) for finding.

Answer (score 2):

Addendum concerning the usage of the term *rule* ... "is it cool to use *rule*?":

The [ISO Prolog Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info) defines **rule** on page 8:

> **3.154 rule**: A *clause* whose *body* is not the *goal* `true`. During execution, if the *body* is true for some *substitution*, then the *head* is
>   also true for that *substitution*. A rule is represented in *Prolog text*
>   by a term whose *principal functor* is `(:-)/2` where the first *argument*
>   is converted to the *head*, and the second *argument* is *converted* to the
>   *body*.

So "rule" is cool.

It is true the "rule" invokes mainly a piece of declarative knowledge known as the **production rule** used in forward-chaining (possibly backward-chaining) expert systems like [CLIPS](http://www.clipsrules.net/AboutCLIPS.html), [Jess](https://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/index.html) or [Drools](https://www.drools.org/), where they can have a

- bottom-up logical/deduction interpretation or
- a non-logical state space trajectory interpretation

...possibly with "search". There are also the "[Constraint Handling Rules](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chr)", which are very much forward-chaining rules that can be compiled into Prolog programs and smoothly integrate with Prolog.

**P.S.**

For an appeal to authority, below is a citation from a blogpost by Robert Kowalski at RuleML.org, written in 2014:

[The Sad State Concerning the Relationships between Logic, Rules and Logic Programming](http://blog.ruleml.org/post/32629706-the-sad-state-concerning-the-relationships-between-logic-rules-and-logic-programming/)

He seems to use:

- *production rule* for a forward chaining rule,
- *reactive rule* for an action-inducing rule (which can be given a logical interpretation in an Abductive Logic Programming framework) and
- *logic programming clause* for, well, the logic programming clause.

> Confusions about the relationships between logic, rules and logic
>   programming are endemic in the world of computing.
>
> ...
>
> I am particularly sensitive to the claim about the difference between
>   deduction and search, because two of my earliest papers (1, 2)
>   investigated the relationship between deduction and search. In my 2011
>   book (3), I discuss Thagard’s (4) various claims about logic and
>   rules, and I argue that there are three varieties of **production
>   rules**:
>
> 1. Rules like *IF you pass forty Arts courses, THEN you graduate with a B.A.* These are logic programming clauses, used to **reason forwards
>      from conditions to conclusions**.
> 2. Rules like *IF you want to go home for the weekend, and you have the bus fare, THEN you can catch a bus*. These are “forward chaining”
>      rules, used to **simulate backward reasoning with logic programming
>      clauses**, such as, you go home for the weekend, if you have the bus
>      fare, and you catch a bus.
> 3. Rules like *IF you are hungry THEN eat something*. These are **reactive rules**, used to make the conclusion of the rule true whenever the condition of the rule becomes true.
>
> In the book, I argue that reactive rules have a more general syntax
>   than logic programming clauses, and they are also more fundamental.
>
> 1. Kowalski, R. (1970), "Search Strategies for
>      Theorem-proving" [PDF](http://aitopics.org/sites/default/files/classic/Machine%20Intelligence%205/MI5-Ch10-Kowalski.pdf).
> 2. Kowalski, R. (1972), "And-or Graphs, Theorem-proving Graphs and
>      Bi-directional Search"
>      [PDF](http://aitopics.org/sites/default/files/classic/Machine_Intelligence_7/MI-7-Ch10-Kowalski.pdf).
> 3. Kowalski, R. (2011) Computational Logic and Human Thinking: How to
>      be Artificially Intelligent, Cambridge University Press.
>      [PDF of draft](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rak/papers/newbook.pdf). [Worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/computational-logic-and-human-thinking-how-to-be-artificially-intelligent/oclc/767671829).
> 4. Thagard, P.
>      (2005) [Mind: Introduction to cognitive science](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/mind). MIT press.

Answer (score 1):

ISO glossary is a little suble. It has also an entry:

> 3.133 predication : A predicate with arity N and a sequence of N arguments .

Since control constructs such as (’,’)/2, etc… are also predicates in Prolog, the above, i.e. the notion predication, is not a prime formula, and this here is correct:

> 3.81 goal : A predication which is to be executed (see body , query , and 7.7.3).`

This differs considerable from the first order logic vocabulary, where logical connectives such as conjunction (∧) are not considered predicates and are therefore not part of the language signature. This ISO core standard specific language, has to do with the homoiconicity of Prolog. Basically we can freely switch between terms, with for example (’,’)/2 as functor and goals which have the same functor. Here is an example what can be done in Prolog:

```
?- expand_goal(H, G), G.
```

The later is not available in first order logic, since first order logic doesn’t allow this kind of “meta-programming”. There was an attempt by John W. Lloyd to create a different language, Prolog inspired language, which would also handle “meta-programming” a different way. The language was:

> Gödel’s meta-logical facilities provide support for meta-programs that do analysis, transformation, compilation, verification, and debugging, among other tasks.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_(programming_language)

The ISO core standard should be seen in this context, that it reflects the very specific capabilities of Prolog concerning “meta-programming”, which is remote from first order logic. This means the terminology in the ISO core standard belongs to an artificial vocabulary, respectively constructed terminology, especially created for Prolog and the ISO core standard.

Its not a language that is found elsewhere in computer science, mathematical logic or the real world. In as far there is nothing to correct or tweak, since it is a terminology created for the purpose of the ISO core standard, and every ammendment with respect to some use elsewhere in computer science, mathematical logic or the real world is simply baseless.

A similar constructed terminology emerged for the DCG draft standard, the many years people were working on it, up to the point that the beloved “push back” was replaced by “semi context”. :-( :-) Since Ulrich Neumerkel saved all versions of the DCG draft standard, you can watch the evolution of the constructed terminology.

I don’t know whether its possible to dig up a document collection that would show the evolution of the terminology in the ISO core standard. Predicate indicator is a Prolog term of the form N/A, predicate is not a Prolog term, but abstractly the pair <N,A>. 3.133 predication is a nice example that can be easier formulated with predicate than with predicate indicator.

Comment: This does not answer the question; this is a related excerpt. If this is meant to be a comment in an answer then please note as such. I know this answer came about because of this [post](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/is-the-definition-of-predicate-correct-in-the-glossary-of-terms/2807?u=ericgt). As I have noted to others that just because it is a nice and useful answer does not mean that this is an answer to this question. Thus I will not be giving it an up-vote.

Comment: @GuyCoder your remark refers to an old version of my answer, I don't think your remark is needed anymore. And my new answer is also reaffirmed by this newer paper: In Praise of Impredicativity: A Contribution to the
   Formalisation of Meta-Programming - François Bry
   https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06051