# What's the difference between functor, a fact, a predicate and a rule in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, terminology

I would like to know the difference between those terms :

1. facts
2. functor
3. predicate.
4. rule

in Prolog.

if I write: `brother(john, jack).`
is that a fact? or a predicate?

Comment: Also SWI Prolog has a good page with the glossary: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this Prolog terminology correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898738/is-this-prolog-terminology-correct)

Comment: FYI When the OP asked the question, the definition of `functor` was not in [Is this Prolog terminology correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49898738/1243762). After seeing the question I updated the other answer with the definition of `functor`. So with the updates it is a duplicate question, but it was no fault of the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From

[ISO/IEC 13211-1 First edition 1995-06-01](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info)
Information technology - Programming languages - Prolog -
Part 1:
General Core

3.9 **arity**: The number of arguments of a compound term. Syntactically, a non-negative integer associated with a functor or predicate.

3.19 **body**: A goal, distinguished by its context as part
of a rule (see 3.154).

3.32 **clause**: A fact or a rule. It has two parts: a head,
and a body.

3.37 **compound term**: A functor of arity N, N positive, together with a sequence of N arguments.

3.72 **fact**: A clause whose body is the goal true.
NOTE - A fact can be represented in Prolog text by a term
whose principal functor is neither `(:-)/1` nor `(:-)/2`.

3.77 **functor**: An identifier together with an arity.

3.81 **goal**: A predication which is to be executed (see
body, query, and 7.7.3).

3.84 **head** (of a rule): A predication, distinguished by its context.

3.88 **identifier**: A basic unstructured object used to denote an atom, functor name or predicate name.

3.129 **predicate**: An identifier together with an arity.

3.133 **predication**: A predicate with arity N and a
sequence of N arguments.

3.143 **query**: A goal given as interactive input to the
top level.

3.154 **rule**: A clause whose body is not the goal true.
During execution, if the body is true for some substitution,
then the head is also true for that substitution. A rule
is represented in Prolog text by a term whose principal
functor is `(:-)/2` where the first argument is converted
to the head, and the second argument is converted to the
body.

So `brother(john, jack).` is a fact.

Comment: `brother(john, jack).` is a fact, a rule, a predicate, and a compound term, depending on context.

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question. Notions like list, unifier etc have nothing to do with the question at all.

Comment: @false rolled back to original answer.

Answer (score 9):

To address your given example:

```
brother(john, jack).
   ^      ^     ^
functor   |     |
      argument  |
            argument
\________  ________/
         \/
   fact/predicate
```

`brother/2` is a predicate AND a fact as well (see **3.72 fact** in @GuyCoder's quote from the standard) since you can write it as a clause with a body that consists of the single goal `true`:

```
brother(john, jack) :-  % <- head of the clause
   true.                % <- body of the clause
```

The predicate `brother` in your example has two arguments, therefore the arity 2 and is referred to as **brother/2** (see **3.129 predicate** in @GuyCoder's post). The name or identifier of the predicate brother/2 is also called the functor of the predicate (see **3.77 functor**; note that 3.77 and 3.129 use the same definition). You can think of a fact as a special kind of predicate that you can define without rules.

If you had some facts `parent_of/2` and `male/2` and defined a predicate `brother_of/2` based on those, e.g...

```
brother_of(X,Y) :-           % X is brother of Y if
   dif(X,Y),                 % X and Y are different AND
   male(X),                  % X is male AND
   parent_of(P,X),           % X has a parent P AND
   parent_of(P,Y).           % Y has the same parent P
```

... then the above definition constitutes a rule because the body of the clause is not the goal `true` (see **3.154 rule**). The rule above consists of the following parts:

```
brother_of(X,Y) :-     % head of the rule
   dif(X,Y),           % goal  \
   male(X),            % goal   \  body of
   parent_of(P,X),     % goal   /  the rule
   parent_of(P,Y).     % goal  /
```

The head of the rule is followed by `:-` which is an implication arrow pointing towards the head of the rule and the goals are separated by `,` which is a logical AND (conjunction). So the body of a rule consists of a single goal or a conjunction of goals and the body of a rule implies the head of the rule. Hence you can read the above definition of brother_of/2 as a logic formula:

`brother_of(X,Y)` ← `dif(X,Y)` ∧ `male(X)` ∧ `parent_of(P,X)` ∧ `parent_of(P,Y)`

If you come from mathematical logic you might find it helpful to recall that a predicate is defined as a boolean-valued function, that is, a function that maps its arguments to *true* or *false*. So a predicate is the characteristic function of a relation (see [Predicate (mathematical logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)). Since you can query facts and get `true`/`false` as an answer, they constitute predicates. You can observe this when you query your definition of brother/2:

```
?- brother(john,jack).
true.                      % <- maps to true

?- brother(john,jason).
false.                     % <- maps to false
```

If you issue queries with variables, you get substitutions for said variables that make the predicate true instead of the answer `true`, e.g.:

```
?- brother(X,Y).
X = john,                  % these substitutions for X and Y
Y = jack.                  % map to true
```

A final remark: When talking about Prolog the terms *predicate* and *relation* are often used interchangeably and it is quite helpful to think about *writing predicates* as *describing relations* (see the comments in the definition of brother_of/2 above). Hence, for the above queries it is also appropriate to say: The relation `brother(john,jack)` *holds*. The relation `brother(john,jason)` *does not hold*. The relation `brother(X,Y)` *holds for the substitutions* `X=john` *and* `Y=jack`.

Comment: @GuyCoder: Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Comment: functor/arguments are not part of any predicate/rule/fact, but of a *compound term*. In turn, compound terms are (usually) used to encode predicates/rules/facts.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between a *term* and a *predicate* (or *goal*) can be subtle. They look the same and are distinguished by context. For example:

```
foo(1).
foo(2).
foo_results(Results) :- setof(X, foo(X), Results).
?- foo_results(Results).
Results = [1, 2].
```

The *predicate* `foo/1` has two clauses. The predicate `foo_results/1` calls this, but indirectly ... the `setof/3` meta-predicate takes a *term* as its second argument, which it interprets as a predicate. In other words, a functor (name/arity) is the skeleton of a kind of  term; some meta-predicates (e.g., `call/1`, `setof/3`, etc.) can interpret a term (functor/arity) as a predicate.

Answer (score 1):

A fact is a predicate expression that makes a declarative statement about the problem domain.

```
likes(john, mary).
```

A rule is a predicate expression that uses logical implication (:-) to describe a relationship among facts. A rule could be

```
left :- right.
friends(X,Y) :- likes(X,Y),likes(Y,X).
```

Both facts and rules are predicates.

So for your question, brother(john, jack) is a fact.