# Prolog: How to read data from console and store into database. Getting errors

Tags: prolog

```
update :-
    write("Name?:"),
    read(Name),
    assert(Name),nl,
    write("Age?:"),
    read(Age),
    assert(Age),
    write("Continue(y or n)?:"),
    read(Respond),
    process(Respond).

process(y) :-
     write('Name?:'),
     read(Name),
     assert(Name),nl,
     write("Age?:"),
     read(Age),
     assert(Age),
     repeat,
     write("y or n"),
     read(Respond),
     process(Respond).

 process(n) :- !.
```

I want to run this Prolog to assert in the name and age, but when I write age for the number, it shows

```
?- update.
Name?:fred.

Age?:|: 25.

ERROR: Type error: `callable' expected, found `25' (an integer)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] assert(25)
ERROR:    [8] update at c:/example.pl:11
ERROR:    [7] <user>
?-
```

How to figure out this problem.

Comment: `assert(something(Age))`?

Comment: yep, I try this way and it works!

Comment: use assert(update(N,A)),

Answer (score 4):

Problem 1

Incorrect input for [assert/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1)

The problem is not with just `Age` it is with any input that uses `assert`, e.g.

```
?- update.
Name?:Fred
|: .

ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] assert(_4940)
ERROR:    [8] update at c:/example.pl:8
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

```
?- update.
Name?:Jim.

ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] assert(_5826)
ERROR:    [8] update at c:/example.pl:8
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

The problem is that [assert/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1) is not being given a fact or rule.
`assert/1` says:

> Assert a clause (fact or rule) into the database.

See [facts and rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Rules_and_facts)

In the example above `Fred` is not a fact because it does not end with a period (`.`).

In the example above with `Jim.` a period was given but because `Jim` starts with a capital letter, it is not a fact or rule but a variable.

When the age is entered as a number, again this is not a fact or rule it is an integer.

Problem 2

Use of [read/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/1) which says:

> Read the next Prolog term from the current input stream and unify it with Term.

When reading a Prolog [term](http://www.dai.ed.ac.uk/groups/ssp/bookpages/quickprolog/node5.html) the input must end with a period.

This not only requires the input to be a term, but end with a `.` which is even more confusing given the prompt, e.g `Age`. Most of the examples you find do what you did, the corrected code below does what you want.

Problem 3

Competing ways or repeating.

The code is using two ways:

1. Use of [repeat/0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=repeat/0)
2. It is [recursive](https://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/recursion.html), e.g.

   ```
   process(y) :-
     ...
     process(Respond).
   ```

This is making it hard to get the code working.

Problem 4

Duplicate code, e.g.

```
write("Name?:"),
read(Name),
assert(Name),nl,
write("Age?:"),
read(Age),
assert(Age),
write("Continue(y or n)?:"),
read(Respond),
process(Respond).
```

Duplicated code is more likely to lead to problems when one copy is corrected and the other copy is not corrected.

---

Problem 1 fix

Make the input a fact before storing in the database with `assert/1`, e.g.

Values in variables

```
Name

Age
```

Variables converted to facts by adding a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53267208/1243762)

```
name(Name)

age(Age)
```

The facts used with `assert/1`

```
assert(name(Name))

assert(age(Age))
```

Problem 2 fix

Use [read_string/5](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_string/5), e.g.

```
read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Name)
```

This reads the input into the variable `Name` as a string. Now that the input is a string, and not a Prolog term, the period is no longer required. There are [predicates that operate on strings](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=string-predicates).

Problem 3 fix

Use the recursion form and remove [repeat/0](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=repeat/0).
This could also use `repeat/0` instead of recursion. The corrected code below uses recursion to demonstrate the change to `process/1`.

Problem 4 fix

Just refactor the code. You can see this in the corrected code at the end.

---

Now with the fixes in place.

Change 1

Since the input for `continue` is no longer a term, e.g. `y` or `n`, but a string, the parameter for `process` needs to be a string, e.g.

```
process("y") :-

process("n") :-
```

Change 2

Age will be asserted as a string but would be better asserted as an integer.

[number_string/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=number_string/2) can solve this, e.g.

```
number_string(Age_n,Age),
assert(age(Age_n))
```

Change 3

user27815 Asked in a comment:

> do you need the cut in process("n") :- !. ?

Since

```
process(Respond).
```

is not creating a choice point, the cut is not needed.

---

Corrected code:

```
update :-
     % Respond will be read as a string and not as a term, so it needs "".
    process("y").

process("y") :-
     write('Name: '),
     read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Name),
     assert(name(Name)),
     write("Age: "),
     read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Age),
     number_string(Age_n,Age),
     assert(age(Age_n)),
     write("Continue: (y or n) "),
     read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Respond),
     process(Respond).

 process("n").
```

Example run:

```
?- update.
Name: Fred
Age: 30
Continue: (y or n) y
Name: Jim
Age: 21
Continue: (y or n) n
true.
```

To check that the database was updated use [listing/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1)

```
?- listing(name/1).
:- dynamic name/1.

name("Fred").
name("Jim").

true.

?- listing(age/1).
:- dynamic age/1.

age(30).
age(21).

true.
```

---

A free enhancement.

Keeping the facts of name and age separate doesn't keep the relation between them intact. A better solution would be a `person` fact with both `Name` and `Age` values.

Here is the necessary modified code.

```
update :-
     % Respond will be read as a string and not as a term, so it needs "".
    process("y").

process("y") :-
     write('Name: '),
     read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Name),
     write("Age: "),
     read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Age),
     number_string(Age_n,Age),
     assert(person(Name,Age_n)),
     write("Continue: (y or n) "),
     read_string(user, "\n", "\r", End, Respond),
     process(Respond).

process("n").
```

Example run:

```
?- update.
Name: Fred
Age: 30
Continue: (y or n) y
Name: Jim
Age: 21
Continue: (y or n) n
true.
```

To check that the database was updated use [listing/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1)

```
?- listing(person/2).
:- dynamic person/2.

person("Fred", 30).
person("Jim", 21).

true.
```

---

After noticing your deleted answer.

In your deleted answer you have

```
?- person(name(N), age(A)).
N = nancy,
A = 22;
N=  steve,
A = 100;
true.
```

The change needed for this variation of the fact to be created is

```
assert(person(name(Name),age(Age_n)))
```

however that might not be the optimal way to go.

In Prolog, positions typically indicate the meaning of a value, e.g. first position is `name` and second position is `age`. In this variation by adding the functors `name` and `age` to the fact `person/2` you are duplicating known knowledge, but more importantly the possibility the amount of work Prolog has to do.

For example:

If the fact was `person(Name,Age).` to get at `Name` and `Age` Prolog only needs one unification. But with `person(Name,Age).` Prolog now needs to unify with `person(name(nancy),age(22))` then to get `Name` has to unify again with `name(nancy)` and to get `Age` has to unify with `age(22)`. You could also use `person(name(Name),age(Age)).` which requires only one unification, but now makes your code more verbose.

When first learning Prolog this crutch helps, but when working with larger data sets, this starts to impact performance.

Another item of note in your deleted answer is that the names of the people are still based on using `read/1`, e.g. `nancy` and `steve`. While a lot of Prolog examples do this, there is no requirement to keep them as such, they can be strings. Odds are the code will never need to exactly match on `nancy` or `steve` and instead will always reference them as a value in a variable. The nice thing about keeping them as strings is that when writing them out, they will appear correctly as `Nancy` and `Steve`.

Comment: do you need the cut in `process("n") :- !.` ? I don't think it is needed.

Comment: @user27815 No the cut is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is because assert does not work on variables. It asserts a fact or rule; in other words, `assert(something)` asserts that `something` must be true.

From the [SWI-Prolog documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assert/1):

> Assert a clause (fact or rule) into the database.

An integer value is not a rule or a fact. It is (in this case) an integer, not something that evaluates to a boolean value. There's no point in asserting a value.

Answer (score 1):

I would write some helpers:

```
read_assert(P,V) :- format('~w ? ',[P]), read(V), A =.. [P,V], assert(A).

?- maplist(read_assert, [name,age], Vs).
name ? capellic.
age ? 99.

Vs = [capellic, 99].

?- name(N).
N = capellic.
```