# functor vs predicate - definition for students

Tags: prolog

The question of the difference between a **functor** and a **predicate** in prolog is asked often.

I am trying to develop an informal definition that is suitable for new students.

> A functor is the **name** of a predicate. The word functor is used when
> discussing **syntax**, such as arity, affix type, and relative priority
> over other functors. The word predicate is used when discussing
> logical and procedural **meaning**.

This looks "good enough" to me.

**Question:**  Is it good enough, or is it fundamentally flawed?

To be clear, I am aiming to develop a useful intuition, not write legalistic text for an ISO standard!

Comment: A functor does not need to be a clause head. I like the definitions at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary#gloss:functor and https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary#gloss:predicate and https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary#gloss:clause

Comment: You are aware that the ISO definitions are the same? See: [Is this Prolog terminology correct? (fact, rule, procedure, predicate, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49931767/1243762)

Comment: For me the problem is that to many people just use `predicate` when they should use a more specific term like `clause`, `predicate indicator`, `predication`, `identifier`, ...

Comment: When using [predicate_property/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=predicate_property/2) came to the realization that it should be named `predication_property/2`, I know it seems a subtle change but it is a change from a one to one relationship to a one to many relationship. Learned that one the hard way when my code kept giving unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

The definition in https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=glossary is:
"functor: Combination of name and arity of a compound term. The term `foo(a,b,c)` is said to be a term belonging to the functor `foo/3`." This does not help a lot, and certainly doesn't explain the difference from a predicate, which is defined: "Collection of clauses with the same functor (name/arity). If a goal is proved, the system looks for a predicate with the same functor, then uses indexing to select candidate clauses and then tries these clauses one-by-one. See also backtracking.".

One of the things that often confuses students is that `foo(a)` could be a term, a goal, or a clause head, depending on the context.

One way to think about term versus predicate/goal is to treat `call/1` as if it is implemented by an "infinite" number of clauses that look like this:

```
call(foo(X)) :- foo(X).
call(foo(X,Y)) :- foo(X,Y).
call(bar(X)) :- bar(X).
```

etc.

This is why you can pass around at term (which is just data) but treat it as a "goal". So, in Prolog there's no need to have a special "closure" or "thunk" or "predicate" data type - everything can be treated as just data and can be executed by use of the `call/1` predicate.

(There are also variations on "call", such as `call/2`, which can be defined as:

```
call(foo, X) :- foo(X).
call(foo(X), Y) :- foo(X, Y).
```

etc.)

This can be used to implement "meta-predicates", such as maplist/2, which takes a list and applies a predicate to each element:

```
?- maplist(writeln, [one,two,three]).
one
two
three
```

where a naïve implementation of maplist/2 is (the actual implementation is a bit more complicated, for efficiency):

```
maplist(_Goal, []).
maplist(Goal, [X|Xs]) :-
    call(Goal, X),
    maplist(Goal, Xs).
```

Comment: With the exception of variables, all terms have a functor, including atoms and numbers (which have arity zero). We can characterize the set of atomic terms as all terms of arity zero. This makes SWI-Prolog glossary definition incomplete/misleading.

Comment: The full content of the glossary does say "foo/0 is used to refer to the atom `foo`" @PauloMoura. It is however incomplete since it doesn't talk about numbers.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by Peter Ludemann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75103998/14411997) is already very good. I want to address the following from your question:

> To be clear, I am aiming to develop a useful intuition, not write legalistic text for an ISO standard!

If you want to develop intuition, **don't bother writing definitions**. Definitions end up being written in legalese or are useless *as definitions*. This is why we sometimes explain by describing how the machine will behave, this is supposedly well-defined, while any statement written in natural language is by definition ambiguous. It is interpreted by a human brain, and you have no idea what is in this brain when it interprets it. As a defense, you end up using legalese to write definitions in natural language.

You can give examples, which will leave some impression and probably develop intuition.

"The Prolog compound term `a(b, c)` can be described by the functor `a/2`. Here, `a` is the term name, and 2 is its arity".

"The functor `foo/3` describes any term with a name `foo` and three arguments."

"Atomic terms by definition have arity 0: for example atoms or numbers. The atom `a` belongs to the functor `a/0`."

"You can define two predicates with the same name, as long as they have a different number of arguments."

There is also the possibility of confusion because some system predicates that allow introspection might take either a functor or the head of the predicate they work on. For example, `abolish/1` takes a functor, while `retractall/1` takes the predicate head.....

Comment: @GuyCoder Ah don't worry about votes. Maybe I need to edit my answer to help you out with your predicament.